# Commas in "The chart shows information about how many people worked from home, in the USA and UK, between 2005 and 2010."

Tags: punctuation, commas

So I've got this sentence in my IELTS prep book:

> The chart shows information about how many people worked from home, in
>   the USA and UK, between 2005 and 2010.

The commas sound so weird. I would be grateful if somebody could explain what are they doing up there.

Actually, the following sentence looks similar but doesn't contain commas:

> The chart highlights data about the amount of electricity which was consumed in India and Pakistan between 2004 and 2010.

What is going on?

Comment: Read up on "parenthetical commas". Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: @Kris, well, I think I have: "If the interruption to the flow of the sentence is but slight, the writer may  safely omit the commas." It seems to me that the interruption to the flow is kinda introduced by those commas up there.

Comment: Much before that, actually. Try to find "what is a parenthetical" in the first place.

Comment: Googling: parenthetical commas. Getting: But if a word or phrase provides necessary information, information that significantly restricts or limits the meaning of the sentence, do not place commas around it. Isn't that the case? We do limit the statistics quite a lot by providing the location.

Comment: @sudoLife The parenthetical is explaining how the info is organized and binned. That is nonessential info as far as the main clause is concerned. Neither sentence is a great example of easily read English. *The chart depicts electrical consumption in India and Pakistan from 2004 to 2010*. The first sentence could be reworded without commas. Using *between* here is considered wrong by some, although it is fairly common. Between X and Y is informal when referring to dates and is usually used for large or imprecise date ranges where the endpoints are more indicative than exact.

Comment: Most comma questions amount to personal style, and that is true in this case.  Yes, you can certainly write that sentence without any commas if you wish.

Comment: @aparente001, great, I was hoping to get such an answer, thanks!

Comment: @PhilSweet All right, it seems like there's no way out of this for me. I'm just going to use whatever feels right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would read the first sentence as indicating that the chart showed separately how many people worked from home in the UK, and also showed how many worked from home in the USA. If the first comma were omitted, I would expect to see a chart showing only the total from both countries combined.

The way the second example is written, I would expect to see only the combined electrical usage of the two countries. If I were describing a chart showing the electrical usage of each, I might say "which was consumed in India and in Pakistan..."

This may or may not be what the author intended, but I believe the meanings are clearer when commas are used in this way and that leaving them out entirely would change the meaning.

Commas are much more than mere optional style. The Panda famously, "Eats, shoots, and leaves."